# Managing secrets and configurations in containers environments

Tags: docker, configuration, kubernetes, cloud, environment

Our platform is based around a Kubernetes / Container based micro-service architecture.

One area we have struggled with is managing environment configs and secrets. Currently we simply have a repository that has three folders for each environment: `/staging, /development, /production`. Inside each folder we have config `.yaml` files that define the secrets and configs for that environment.

The issue is our workflow is exposed to mistakes:

1. Developer needs to update a config / secret
2. Opens folder with specific config
3. Pulls any changes from ops-repo
4. Updates the config values
5. Apply them to the environment
6. Commits and pushes changes to ops-repo

Are there tooling / workflows that can take the manual/human side of this away?

Comment: Commiting the secrets into the Git repository is not ideal, might be worthwhile to look into something like [Vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault)

Comment: Yes considered vault already although we would love a unified config/secret tool...! Plus vault its a complex integration. We are a small team.